# Why Navigation graph destroy old fragment when it launches new Fragment and How to overcome this?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-navigation-graph

I have developed an Android app with 5 fragments in Single Activity architecture using a Navigation graph. The issue right now I'm facing is each fragment is destroyed when a new fragment launches when I back pressed old fragment is recreated and a UI glitch is observed. There is no need for fragment recreation. Why this is occurring and How to overcome this?

Comment: The fragment is destroyed(onDestroy) or the UI of the fragment is destroyed(onDestroyView)?

Comment: UI of the fragment is destroyed is destroyed

Comment: Well, AFAIK that is intended behavior. If you have any glitch in UI, that is the core of your problem.